# how to determine which segmented control is selected outside of sender func in swift

Tags: swift, uisegmentedcontrol

Please forgive new to swift-ness. I'm creating a BMI Calculator app. The app allows the user to select Imperial or Metric using a segmented control. Based on the segmented control, I change the placeholder text. Upon the 'Calculate' button, I call an extension to do the calculation. My question is: in this action of button pressed, how do I determine which segment is selected, so I can adjust the calculation? This is my current code:

```
@IBAction func segmentChanged(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        textInputHeight.placeholder = "Enter height in inches"
        textInputWeight.placeholder = "Enter weight in pounds"
    }
    else {
        textInputHeight.placeholder = "Enter height in centimeters"
        textInputWeight.placeholder = "Enter weight in kilograms"
    }
}

@IBAction func CalulateBMIButton() {
    if let height = textInputHeight.text.toDouble() {
        if let weight = textInputWeight.text.toDouble() {
            let bmiCalc = BMICalculator(height: height, weight: weight)
            labelOutputBMI.text = "BMI is: \(round(10.0 * bmiCalc.bmi) / 10)"
            labelOutputBMI.hidden = false
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need an outlet to the UISegmentedControl

```
@IBOutlet weak var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!
```

Then you can access the current selection using.

```
segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you. I forgot I needed to make it an outlet also, I tried segmentChanged.selectedSegmentIndex and couldn't get what was wrong. Thanks again.